# PHP parse value + URL data from database value

Tags: php

First sorry for my bad english

Ok I'm having trouble showing data to my website

I have script like this :

```
<a href="123" data-popup="lightbox" btn-rounded">
```

This data : `123` is value from database. But sometimes my data contain like this

```
<img src="http://xxx/images/abc.gif">
```

All data's without img src fine but when img src appear my url broke just like this :

```
<a href="123 <img src="http://xxx/images/abc.gif">" data-popup="lightbox" btn-rounded">
```

I've tried using explode after use strpos to find specific word

```
$string = '123 <img src="http://www.xxx/images/abc.gif">';
$array=explode(" ",$string); 
echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
```

But result's only show value `123`

How do I parse my value and img src data?

Anyway, this is my current PHP script

```
<?PHP
    $res=$mySite->GetUpdateManga(12);
    while($data=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    echo 
    '<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6">
    <div class="thumbnail">
    <div class="thumb">
        <img src="http://xxx'.$data['manga_pic'].'" class="lazy" style="height:269px;" alt="" />
    <div class="caption-overflow">
    <span>';
        if (strpos($data['last_chapter'], '<img src="http://xxx//images/hot.gif">' OR '<img src="http://xxx/images/hot.gif"')  !== false) {
            echo '<a href="'.$data['last_chapter'].'" data-popup="lightbox" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded">';
        }
        else {
            $array=explode("<",$data['last_chapter']);
            echo '<a href="'.$array[0].'"'.'<'.$array[1].' data-popup="lightbox" class="btn border-white text-white btn-flat btn-icon btn-rounded">';           
        }
        echo '<i class="icon-book3"></i></a>
    </span>
    </div>
    </div>

    <div class="caption">
        <h6 class="no-margin-top text-semibold">
            <a href="'.$data['manga_link'].'" class="text-default">'.$data['manga_name'].'</a>
        </h6> beberapa jam nyang lalu
    </div>

    <div class="panel-footer no-padding">
        <a href="series/read.php" class="btn btn-default btn-block no-border">Baca Chapter '.$data['last_chapter'].'</a>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    ';
    }
?>
```

Thanks

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve. `123 <img src="http://xxx/images/abc.gif">"` isn't a URL. I can't see any way that it would belong in an `href` attribute. What is your desired outcome?

Comment: You better fix the data in the database.

Comment: You question is very hard to understand can you please describe what you're trying to do a bit more clearly. and if you want to create links whay do you have image tags in your data base.

Comment: first, `base64_encode` your data..second put that data in `data-attribute` instead in `src`.then when u want to grab the data, simply `base64_decode` it

Comment: @Quentin I'm trying to parse 2 value, 123 and <img src>

Comment: @axiac I'm on it, but currently I'd like to fix this first because it's in production, my data's more than 10k :(

Comment: @Fahmi — And do what with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to explode by `<` delimiter. After `explode` operation, the `<` character from the `img` tag is removed. You have to add it again to your result string like this:

```
$string = '123 <img src="http://www.xxx/images/abc.gif">';
$array=explode("<",$string); 
echo '<'.$array[1];
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $array[0], $matches);
$number = $var = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
echo $number;
```